# Div to change position in responsive mode

Tags: responsive-design

I have 3 elements in my header (A, B, and C), where A and C are static images, and B is a fluid div of text.

What I would like to happen when I reduce my screen size (or view on a mobile device) is that B drops below both, while A and C remain in place--each at opposite sides of the screen.

See this illustration.

http://craigaranha.com/responsiveheader/

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Float the left box to the left, the right box to the right, and let the middle box fill the remaining space. Then when the screen is smaller, just add `clear:both` on the middle box to make it drop down.

Something like this:

```
.left, .right {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
}
.left {
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
}
.right {
  background-color:magenta;
  float:right;
}

.middle {
  background-color:silver;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
}

@media all and (max-width:800px) {
  .middle {
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

Assuming markup like this:

```
<div class="left">A</div>
<div class="right">C</div>
<div class="middle">B is a fluid box of text.</div>
```

[Example codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FBHha)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I can't be 100% sure what your CSS structure is but you could start with `@media screen and (min-device-width: XXXpx) { }` or `@media screen and (min-width: XXXpx){ }`. They'll detect the device screen size and give you some conditional CSS rules. Within those those rules, if your right/left divs are floated, you could float the third and use `clear:both`, or your could use `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`. It really depends on your document structure and current CSS. Hopefully this has given you a starting point though.

Personally I think `position:fixed;` would be too much of a quick and dirty solution, the same would go for `position:absolute;`.